# What's wrong in concatinating and using the return type of mysqli_insert_id()?

Tags: php, mysql

The error is shown on this line :

```
$query1="UPDATE `users` 
         SET password=''.md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($link).$pass)).'' 
         WHERE id=''.mysqli_insert_id($link).'' ";
```

Error is as follows :

> **Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string 
>       in /home/vhosts/nagarajhegde41.freevar.com/DiaryHome.php on line 30**

Comment: You have you functions in quotes. They are not going to run.

Comment: Your string is enclosed in double quotes but you are tryng to terminate it and concatenate with single `"UPDATE \`users\` 
         SET password=''.` <--- in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying in [string parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) to execute code inside text but you didn't get the syntax right. My advice is that you don't even try. Packing code in strings is inconvenient to say the least. Just see how easy it gets with regular code statements:

```
$query1 = 'UPDATE users
    SET password = ?
    WHERE id = ?';
$params1 = [
    md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($link).$pass)),
    mysqli_insert_id($link),
];
```

This way you get for free:

- Simpler syntax.
- Readable code.
- Proper syntax highlighting and code completion in all PHP editors (even free ones).
- Proper error reporting, with useful line number information.
- Protection against SQL injection.

P.S. You might want to check [Password Hashing Functions](https://www.php.net/password).

Comment: But how will functions work inside the whole string that you suggested to be passed, functions like mysqli_real_escape_string() or mysqli_insert_id()? if i wanna use the, i have to use concat, right?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your follow-up question. `.` is the [concatenation operator in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), if that's what you mean.